# Cannot add label to geom_hline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

#this is my sample data set-I think this is the correct format for stack overflow, but if not I can try something else

```
    Date        Analyte                Result
    3/1/2016    Total Phosphorus        1.25
    5/1/2016    Total Phosphorus        1.1
    7/1/2017    Total Phosphorus        0.33
    11/1/2016   Total Organic Nitrogen  1.3
    1/1/2017    Total Organic Nitrogen  1.1
    3/1/2017    Total Organic Nitrogen  0.7
    ----------
```

## this is the code I used to create my scatter plot and add the lines, but I cannot get the labels to work. I would like to label both geom_hlines.  My data set is named tptn

```
tptn$Date <- as.Date(tptn$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
        p<-ggplot(tptn, aes(x=Date, y=Result, group=Analyte, color=Analyte))  + 
            ggtitle("Average Total Phosphorus and Total Organic Nitrogen in Pond 7") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + xlab("Month") + 
            ylab("mg/L") + geom_point(size = 4) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0)) + 
            scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("2 month"),labels = date_format("%b %Y")) 
            + geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1, linetype = 2, colour='turquoise4', size = 1) 
            + 
            geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, linetype = 3, colour = 'red', size = 1) 
            p<-p+expand_limits(y=0) 
            p + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0.1))
    #tried this
        p + annotate(geom="text", x=3, y=2, label="Total Phosphorus",
                  color="red")
    #tried this
        + geom_text(data=tptn(x=0,y=0.1), aes(x, y), label=Total Phosphorus, vjust=-1)
```

## These work independently, but I cannot get labels to show up on both lines

```
p + annotate(geom="text", x=as.Date("2016-09-01"), 
             y=0.18, label="Total Phosphorus Threshold", fontface="bold", colour='turquoise4') 
p + annotate(geom="text", x=as.Date("2017-9-01"), 
             y=0.9, label="Total Nitrogen Threshold", fontface="bold", colour='red')
#The figure is of my full data set
```

[image: My full data set]

Comment: Your annotate attempt uses a `y` value of 2. Does your `y` scale go that high? Does it work if you use a value close to your line, like `y = 0.85`?

Comment: My scale does go close to 2.  I tried putting in y=0.85 but that didn't work either.  I get this error when I run the annotate code Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Comment: The error is correct. You need your x axis is a date so you need to specify the x position of the annotation as a date

Comment: Thank you @ Jack Brookes - is it possible to label both of my lines?

Comment: I added the new code (with the date) into my script above-but can only get one label to show up at a time

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: If you have `x = 10`, then `x+1` and `x+2` will give you 11 and 12. To get to 13 (both at once), do `x  = x + 1; x = x +2; x`. To get both your annotations, `p = p + annotate(<first one>); p = p + annotate(<second one>); p`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just have the text off the x-axis. Simply pulling it in works.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

dat <- data.frame(Date = c('3/1/2016', '5/1/2016', '7/1/2017', '11/1/2016', '1/1/2017', '3/1/2017'),
           Analyte = c('Total Phosphorus', 'Total Phosphorus', 'Total Phosphorus', 'Total Organic Nitrogen', 'Total Organic Nitrogen',  'Total Organic Nitrogen'),
           Result = c(1.25, 1.1, 0.33, 1.3, 1.1, 0.7))  

dat %>% 
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Date, Result, color = Analyte)) + geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.1, linetype = 2, colour='turquoise4', size = 1) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.8, linetype = 3, colour = 'red', size = 1) +
  annotate(geom="text", x = as.Date("2016-09-01"), 
           y = 0.18, label = "Total Phosphorus Threshold", fontface="bold", colour='turquoise4') +
  annotate(geom="text", x = as.Date("2017-04-01"), 
           y = 0.85, label = "Total Nitrogen Threshold", fontface="bold", colour='red') +
  ggtitle("Average Total Phosphorus and Total Organic Nitrogen in Pond 7") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + xlab("Month") + 
  ylab("mg/L") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1.0, hjust = 1.0))
```